# Capabilities and Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I have a custom post type that I'd like to restrict access to certain roles however, I've already added content using the custom post type and now I have to make them restricted. The capability_type was 'post'

```
'capability_type' => 'post'
```

Which is fine as the content show up in the backend however, now as soon as I add any capabilities the content disappears from the backend?

I've tried customising the capability type to include plural definitions to construct my own but as soon as I remove or change capability types it's gone!

full code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_gallery' );

function register_cpt_gallery() {
$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'gallery' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'View Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Galleries', 'gallery' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'No galleries found', 'gallery' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No galleries found in Trash', 'gallery' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Gallery:', 'gallery' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'Image galleries for teachers classes',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author'),

    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,

    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/imagegallery.png',
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post' => 'edit_gallery',
        'edit_posts' => 'edit_galleries',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_galleries',
        'publish_posts' => 'publish_galleries',
        'read_post' => 'read_gallery',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_galleries',
        'delete_post' => 'delete_gallery'
    )
);

register_post_type( 'gallery', $args );
}
```

I've also tested this with a completely new custom post type and regardless of the capability type I get the same issue eg even if I remove it and add my custom one:

```
'capability_type' => array('movie','movies');
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

After a quick chat with [Magicroundabout](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/10046/magicroundabout) who pointed out a useful resource from [Justin Tadlock](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/anyone-managed-to-get-custom-post-types-capabilities-working/page/2#post-1593534), it turns out that capabilities for custom post types don't actually exist unless you use add_cap to the role, for example for the following custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_gallery' );

function register_cpt_gallery() {
$labels = array( 
    'name' => __( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'gallery' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Gallery', 'gallery' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Galleries', 'gallery' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'No galleries found', 'gallery' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No galleries found in Trash', 'gallery' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Gallery:', 'gallery' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description' => 'Image galleries for teachers classes',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/imagegallery.png',
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post' => 'edit_gallery',
        'edit_posts' => 'edit_galleries',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_galleries',
        'publish_posts' => 'publish_galleries',
        'read_post' => 'read_gallery',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_galleries',
        'delete_post' => 'delete_gallery'
    ),
    // as pointed out by iEmanuele, adding map_meta_cap will map the meta correctly 
    'map_meta_cap' => true
);

register_post_type( 'gallery', $args );
}
```

The additional capabilities should be added to a role for the permissions to actually work in the backend, including the 'administrator' - for example:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the administrator role
    $admins = get_role( 'administrator' );

    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_gallery' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_other_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'publish_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_gallery' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_private_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'delete_gallery' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

I hope this is useful to others.

Additionally, the `_x()` translation function expects the second argument to be `string $context`, which is a short description, and the third to be `string $domain`. When not providing a description, use the `__()` translation function instead which has the `string $domain` as the second argument.

Comment: `add_theme_caps()` should be called one time only, not everytime an admin page is loaded. It would be better to use `switch_theme` as hook for theme activation or `register_activation_hook` on plugin activation.

Comment: Nice! I like to use wp cli to add the capabilities if it's a completely custom/unique site since it's an action that only needs to happen once.

Answer (score 12):

Add:

```
map_meta_cap => true
```

to your $args array. Look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), for more.
Hope it helps!

Comment: This is what I thought also but not totally the case.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you never map your own capabilities. Make sure to use map meta cap plugin to do so.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap

I spent days trying to map my custom caps manually with code. Just install that plugin, map your caps and deactivate once working. If creating custom roles you WILL need [Members](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin) plugin.

The way I test to MAKE sure my role has those capabilites (sometimes you swear you do but don't actually) make a debugging page with:

```
    if( !function_exists( 'current_user_has_role' ) ){
        function current_user_has_role( $role ){
            $current_user = new WP_User( wp_get_current_user()->ID );
            $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
            $is_or_not = in_array( $role, $user_roles );
            return $is_or_not;
        }
    }
```

This will show you which capabilities you do in fact have.

Answer (score 0):

For Custom Post Types, I **DON'T** suggest using hook:

```
add_action( 'registered_post_type', 'your_func', 10, 2 );
```

instead I suggest using:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'your_func', 10, 2 );
function your_func( $args, $name ) 
{
   if ( $name == "your_custom_post_name" ) 
   ...
}
```

Comment: the suggestion is a good one, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: I don't even understand why it's a good suggestion. That action is called from post.php at the bottom of register_post_type, and passes the type and object back to any code that wants to handle it. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this. Though nothing in this Q&A referred to this action anyway. ;)