# user has permission to read a custom post but it is not being shown in wordpress plugin

Tags: user-roles

I created a new role: 'student' and student capabilities are as follows:

```
add_role(
            'student',
            __( 'Student' ),
            array(
                   'read' => true,  // true allows this capability

               )
        );
```

I wanted to give all student to read a custom post type: 'Assignment'. But when I login as student I can't see any menu item named: Assignment. But when I login as 'teacher' I can see this 'assignment' menu. Here is the 'teacher' role capability:

```
  add_role(
            'teacher',
            __( 'Teacher' ),
            array(
                'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
                'edit_posts'   => true,
                'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
            )
        );
```

Why student can't see assignment menu. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `'read' => true` [allows you](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#read) to access the Dashboard and the Profile. No other stuff if not explicitly stated.

Comment: So, What should I do for my requirements?

Comment: I am not sure why do you need 'Student' and 'Teacher' roles when 'Subscriber' and 'Contributor' already has the same capabilities. In case you want them to have access only to a custom post type, you have to [create capabilities](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108375/11761) instead of using the defaults, for example, `read_assignment`, `edit_assignment`, `edit_assignments`, `edit_others_assignments` and so on.