# WordPress: Custom User Role cannot access Custom Post Type | "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page"

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, user-roles, capabilities

**The Objective:**
Create a custom post type and only give administrator and a custom role permission to view / control it.

**The Problem:**
For administrators, it works perfectly fine but for the custom role I get:
`Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

At first, I thought it could just be a matter of capability to access it, but this bit of code begs to differ:

```
add_submenu_page( /*  STAFF PAGES   */
                'redacted', //Parent Menu Slug
                'Staff Pages', //Page Title text
                'Staff Pages', //Menu Title text
                'edit_staff', //Capability required for this menu to be displayed by user
                'edit.php?post_type=staff' //Link to page
);
```

The custom role can see the link to the custom post type but cannot access it. Also, running `print_r($wp_roles->get_role( 'supervisor' )->capabilities);` does show that the role correctly possesses the necessary capabilities. I've had a few theories as to how to solve this, but so far none have panned out.

My code is as follows:

```
function initialize_plugin(){
//Non-relevant code redacted
add_action( 'admin_init', array($this, 'admin_init') );
}
function activate(){
    $this->custom_post_types();
    $this->adjust_user_roles();
    //Non-relevant code redacted
}



/* My Custom Post Type */
function custom_post_types(){
            register_post_type( 'staff', array(
                'labels' => array(
                    //labels redacted
                ),
                'has_archive'       => false,
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-groups',
                'capability_type'   => array('staff', 'staffs'),
                'map_meta_cap'      => true,
                'public'            => true,
                'show_in_menu'      => false,
                'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'staff', 'with_front' => false ),
                'supports'          => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions'),
                'show_in_rest'      => true,
                'taxonomies'        => array( 'member-type' ),
                'menu_position'     => 2,
            ));



/* My Custom Role */
function adjust_user_roles(){
$wp_roles = new WP_Roles(); 

$wp_roles->add_role(
              'supervisor', __( 'Supervisor' ),
               array(
                    //General
                    'moderate_comments'         => true,
                    'upload_files'              => true,
                   
                    //Blog Posts
                    'read'                      => true,
                    'read_post'                 => true,
                    'edit_post'                 => true,
                    'edit_posts'                => true,
                    'edit_others_posts'         => true,
                    'delete_posts'              => false, //Can't delete posts

                    //Staff (Custom Post Type)
                    'create_staffs'             => true,
                    'read_staff'                => true,
                    'edit_staff'                => true,
                    'edit_staffs'               => true,
                    'edit_others_staffs'        => true,
                    'edit_published_staffs'     => true,
                    'edit_private_staffs'       => true,
                    'delete_staff'              => true,
                    'delete_others_staffs'      => true,
                    'delete_published_staffs'   => true,
                    'delete_private_staffs'     => true,
                    'publish_staffs'            => true,
                    'read_private_staffs'       => true,
              )
);



/* Adding to administrator */
function admin_init(){
   //Non-relevant code redacted
   $this->adjust_user_capabilities("add");
}

function adjust_user_capabilities($action, $roles=array('administrator','editor', 'supervisor')){
  $staffCaps = array(
                'create_staff',
                'read_staff',
                'edit_staff',
                'edit_staffs',
                'edit_others_staffs',
                'edit_published_staffs',
                'edit_private_staffs',
                'delete_staff',
                'delete_others_staffs',
                'delete_published_staffs',
                'delete_private_staffs',
                'publish_staffs',
                'read_private_staffs',              
            );

            //Cycle through each role
            foreach($roles as $roleType) :
                $role = get_role( $roleType );
            
                //Add each capability
                if($action == "add"){
                    foreach($staffCaps as $staffCap){   
                        $role->add_cap( $staffCap );
                    }
                }
            
                //Remove each capability
                elseif($action == "remove"){
                    foreach($staffCaps as $staffCap){
                        $role->remove_cap( $staffCap );
                    }
                }
            endforeach;
}
```

**NOTE:**
This code appears in `wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php`. In addition, I have redacted some non-relevant portions of my code for clarity, such as adding or removing a submenu, and tried to expound more of the structure. Feel free to let me know if there is anything I missed or anyone has questions on. :-D

**In Closing:**
I could just be a major idiot overlooking something obvious, but regardless, any and all help / advice / suggestions are highly appreciated! If I get the answer on my own, I'll add it to this discussion to help anyone else out facing a similar problem and/or my future self lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
With some playing around I realized I am definitely an idiot and WAY over-thought things. While I had previously read and tried some of the things in [this similar post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299859/custom-post-type-role-permissions-wont-let-me-read), I ended up substituting their code for mine and found it actually worked for my use case. In trying to understand why that was, I began trying to convert it to become mine and quickly found the root of my problem:

```
/* My Custom Post Type */
function custom_post_types(){
            register_post_type( 'staff', array(
                'labels' => array(
                    //labels redacted
                ),
                'has_archive'       => false,
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-groups',
                'capability_type'   => array('staff', 'staffs'),
                'map_meta_cap'      => true,
                'public'            => true,
/*---------> */ 'show_in_menu'      => false, /* <---------*/
                'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'staff', 'with_front' => false ),
                'supports'          => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions'),
                'show_in_rest'      => true,
                'taxonomies'        => array( 'member-type' ),
                'menu_position'     => 2,
            ));
```

In an effort to have a clean custom menu, I set `show_in_menu` to false which created the issues for me. When I changed it to `'show_in_menu' => true`, my issue was resolved. In addressing this, I am tempted to just try `remove_menu_page();` or perhaps consider something more elegant.

Anyways, the lesson for today is not to be hyper-focused on one aspect. Hopefully this helps someone else and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

After your custom post registration complete use below type code it will help you as reference.

```
/**
 * Post Type: Blogs.
 */
function cptui_register_blog_cpts() {


    $labels = [
        "name" => __( "Blogs", "oba" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Blog", "oba" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Blogs", "oba" ),
        "all_items" => __( "All Blogs", "oba" ),
        "add_new" => __( "Add Blog", "oba" ),
        "add_new_item" => __( "Add New Blog", "oba" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Edit Blog", "oba" ),
        "new_item" => __( "New Blog", "oba" ),
        "view_item" => __( "View Blog", "oba" ),
        "view_items" => __( "View Blog", "oba" ),
        "search_items" => __( "Search Blogs", "oba" ),
        "not_found" => __( "No Blogs Found", "oba" ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( "No Blogs found in Trash", "oba" ),
        "parent" => __( "Parent Blog", "oba" ),
        "featured_image" => __( "Featured image for this Blog", "oba" ),
        "set_featured_image" => __( "Set Featured image for this Blog", "oba" ),
        "remove_featured_image" => __( "Remove featured Image for this Blog", "oba" ),
        "use_featured_image" => __( "Use as featured image for this Blog", "oba" ),
        "archives" => __( "Blogs Archive", "oba" ),
        "insert_into_item" => __( "Insert into Blog", "oba" ),
        "uploaded_to_this_item" => __( "Uploaded to this Blog", "oba" ),
        "filter_items_list" => __( "Filter Blogs List", "oba" ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( "Blog List Navigation", "oba" ),
        "items_list" => __( "Blogs list", "oba" ),
        "attributes" => __( "Blogs Attributes", "oba" ),
        "name_admin_bar" => __( "Blog", "oba" ),
        "item_published" => __( "Blog Published", "oba" ),
        "item_published_privately" => __( "Blog Published privately", "oba" ),
        "item_reverted_to_draft" => __( "Blog reverted to draft", "oba" ),
        "item_scheduled" => __( "Blog scheduled", "oba" ),
        "item_updated" => __( "Blog updated", "oba" ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( "Parent Blog", "oba" ),
    ];

    $args = [
        "label" => __( "Blogs", "oba" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "This is a post type of Blog reading page",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "blog",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "blog", "with_front" => true ],
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => [ "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "custom-fields", "comments", "revisions", "author"],
        "taxonomies" => [ "blog_category", "blog_post_tag", "blog_post_author_name" ],
        // "capabilities" => array( 
        //         "manage_terms" => "manage_categories", 
        //         "edit_terms" => "manage_categories", 
        //         "delete_terms" => "manage_categories", 
        //         "assign_terms" => "edit_posts" 
        //     ), 
    ];

    register_post_type( "blog", $args );
    register_taxonomy('blog_category', 'blog', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Blog Category', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog-category' )));
    // register_taxonomy('blog_post_author_name', 'blog', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'E-Books Author', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog-post-author-name' )));
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_blog_cpts' );

/**
 ** add teachers capability
 */
add_action('admin_init','blog_add_role_caps',999);
    function blog_add_role_caps() {

        // Add the roles you'd like to administer the custom post types
        $roles = 'administrator';

        // Loop through each role and assign capabilities
        // foreach($roles as $the_role) {    
             // $role = get_role($the_role);               
             $role = get_role($roles);               
             $role->add_cap( 'read' );
             $role->add_cap( 'read_blog');
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_blog' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_blogs' );
             $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_blogs' );
             $role->add_cap( 'publish_blogs' );
             $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_blogs' );
        // }
        }
        /**
 * Overwrite args of custom post type registered by plugin
 */
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_capabilities_of_blog' , 10, 2 );

function change_capabilities_of_blog( $args, $post_type ){

 // Do not filter any other post type
 if ( 'blog' !== $post_type ) {

     // Give other post_types their original arguments
     return $args;

 }

 // Change the capabilities of the "book" post_type
 $args['capabilities'] = array(
            'edit_post' => 'edit_blog',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_blogs',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_blogs',
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_blogs',
            'read_post' => 'read_blog',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_blogs',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_blog',
        );

  // Give the course_document post type it's arguments
  return $args;

}
```

Comment: Much appreciation for the response! While it didn't work in my case, see below, I am sure it'll help someone that finds this in the future. Thanks for the solid advice, man! :-D

Comment: OK, I was edited my previous code so you copy that code and pest that in your function.php file. It must work.